# Character to vector in R

Tags: r

I have 3 binary vectors.

```
a<-c(0,0,1,0)
b<-c(1,0,0,0)
c<-c(0,0,0,1)
```

I need to choose 2 out of 3 vectors and check whether they are subsets. I have used **combn** function as bellow:

```
> combination<-combn(letters[1:3], 2)
> combination
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "a"  "a"  "b" 
[2,] "b"  "c"  "c"
```

But the problem is- all the elements in combination are characters. How can I connect these elements (which are letters) to the binary vector?

For example if I call `combination[1,1]` I can get binary vector **a** (not "a").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `get` to *search by name for an object*.

```
get(combination[1,1])
#[1] 0 0 1 0
```

or `mget` for more:

```
do.call(cbind, mget(combination[,1]))
#     a b
#[1,] 0 1
#[2,] 0 0
#[3,] 1 0
#[4,] 0 0
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest working in a list for this. It very well may make life easier down the line.

```r
vec_list <- list(a = a, b = b, c = c)

vec_list[combination[1,1]]
```

Which gives this:

```r
$a
[1] 0 0 1 0
```

You could easily convert that to a `data.frame()`, vector, or whatever as needed from there.

Comment: MIght add for clarity (for newcomers to `list`) that  `vec_list[[1]]` and `vec_list[['a']]` will return the same thing, and also to "beware" of  `x[[i, exact = TRUE]]`  vs. exact = FALSE

Answer (score 1):

We can also wrap with `data.frame`

```
data.frame(mget(combination[,1]))
```